# Usage of the 'not an answer' flag

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Not sure if this is the best way to raise this, but I'm at odds with a flag that was 'declined' as the answer to an old question (which in itself isn't a proper SO question) when the person basically answered with I think X is better because of y which is just a highly subjective one line answer with no facts or real info.

> I think that the best one is the Jersey. For example in Netbeans the
>   integration is full

Now personally, my biggest issue is losing 10 flag points (which is a large amount when you're nearing 700) and the question was closed due to what I view was my highlighting of a 'non answer' answer. (Edit: It's not really a big deal, but I'm gonna pretend it is) ;)

So probably my question is, is there anyway to discuss or at least say 'I'm not happy with the response' on a flag? (and can it be changed to a disputed rather than decline.)

(for reference, the question and answer is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710199/which-is-the-best-java-rest-api-restlet-or-jersey/8465958#8465958)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is here. It's a valid answer, only not a very good one. The moderator *could* have marked your flag as helpful because it pointed him to a question that needed to be closed, but apparently didn't, so yeah.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There were flags on at least two answers in that post by you and I handled [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733356/419) and marked it as helpful. The only reason I did that was **not** because I agreed with your assertion that it was "not an answer" but because it brought my attention to the question itself which was a "do-not-ask" type question.

The mod who processed the second flag after I closed the question did the right thing. It's not a great answer but it is an answer all the same.

Your focus should have been on why the question was attracting such less than stellar answers and you should have flagged the question as "Not Constructive" instead.

I also went to have a look at your profile and in particular your flagging history and see this:

> Currently working towards a Flag ranking of 700 before 2012, will I make it?

If your sole aim is to score flag weight points then you're here for the wrong reason. You should spend some time earning rep to open up the [full range of tools available](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to help make Stack Overflow a better place.

Comment: THanks Kev, this is the sort of info I was hoping to get from this.  :)   As to the Flag ranking bit on my profile, it's just a mini-target to aim for, It seemed more obtainable than say hitting 2k rep by 2012 :) and was a nice round number

Answer (score 4):

*Usage of the not an answer flag*

> Who uses Restlet? <<< not an answer
>   New Jersey is the best place ever! <<< not an answer
>   Collect cheap rolex watches <<< spam

You flagged an answer that

- *did* answer the question  (subjective question got a subjective answer)
- it's not an edit
- it's not a comment
- it shouldn't be deleted because of the first point

I think the decision to decline your flag was correct

> which is just a highly subjective one line answer with no facts or real inf...

You should have flagged the question as not constructive (lost your chance on flag weight there). But a mod closed the question now.

> So probably my question is, is there anyway to discuss or at least say 'I'm not happy with the response' on a flag?

Yup, here in meta, though mods don't make mistakes frequently so the decision will most likely not be changed.

Comment: "[...] though mods don't make mistakes frequently so the decision will most likely not be changed." -- That's not a reason, and in any case the decision *can't* be changed.

Comment: In hindsight I should have just flagged the question and left as is, but as there is no way to cancel a flag, (another question I'd asked before) it really doesn't encorage people to continue flagging once they hit the magic 749 number (who'd want to get all the way to that and then get one 'wrong' and be 100+ away from 749 again)

Comment: The decision to change *action* of what the flag wanted can always be changed. Except when a user is destroyed. @lunboks I guess you thought  I was talking about the flag itself. If a mod reviewed a flag and declined it. He/se (98%) time knows what he/she is doing. There are not that many questions in the [declined-flags] tag.

Answer (score 3):

What I've seen happening is that response to flags only happens through posts like this...

About this issue though, "I think X is better because of y" seems like a valid answer to "Which is the best Java REST API - Restlet or Jersey?". The only thing that seems off there is the question.